# Elasticsearch 5.4 Pagination with NEST for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I know, I'm so stupid that I cannot see how, but I'm new with elasticsearch.

I want to know how can i do a simple pagination.

> Like: 1 To 10 Of **123,456** entries

I need to know the total hits for the query, have sense right?

```
    public long GetCount(SearchModel model)
    {
        return _elasticClient.Search<Document>(s => s
            .Query(q => GetWhere(q, model))
        ).Total;

    }
```

I'm not using From/Size because I want to get the total records for the query (that simple).

I tried ISearchResponse.Total and that ignores the query filters

some advice will be very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a simple document search you should probably just use `From` and `Size` for paging. The returned result should have a hits.total representation which is the total number of documents matching your query.
The hits collection though will only have the 10 documents or whatever you define in (size).

Example for From/Size:

```
var response = client.Search<Tweet>(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Query(q =>
        q.Term(t => t.User, "kimchy")
        || q.Match(mq => mq.Field(f => f.User).Query("nest"))
    )
);
```

`response.HitsMetaData.Total` should have the total number of docs found.

Comment: you must use 'HitsMetadata' with lower case 'd'.